# bundle install does not work and says undefined methods (trying to install ruby on rails on ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle-install

I'm trying to install Ruby on rails on my ubuntu, I've installed everything for Ruby on rails to work, I've created my ruby on rails project but when I run ruby server they say "run bundle install" but whenever I run it I get :

```
/snap/ruby/247/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:1340:in `rescue in <top (required)>': undefined method `rubyforge_project=' for class `Gem::Specification' (NameError)
Loading the rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb file caused an error.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install ruby manually, rbenv, rvm and update RubyGems manually

Here is a good guide to walk you through the proccess
https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/21.04